# Double tap in bottom navigaton bar item Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my home page i have a bottom navigation with 2 menu.

I have origin library `bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar`

In original library there is no property `onDoubleTap`

Are there any technique to implement with it.

Here what I do now

```
List<Widget> _widgetOptions;
int _selectedIndex = 0;
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  HomeScreen(),
  SettingScreen();
];
 }
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: IndexedStack(
    children: _widgetOptions,
    index: _selectedIndex,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/home.png",
        ),
        activeIcon: Image.asset(
          "assets/icons/home_active.png",
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/icons/service.png",
          ),
          activeIcon: Image.asset(
            "assets/icons/service.png",
          ),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Create a Container and add a double tap to it

Comment: it doesn't allow to wrap with container.

Comment: @Viroth can you share your code?

Comment: @Viroth wrapping the `BottomNavigationBar` with a `GestureDetector` widget will work. check out in answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GestureDetector` widget and wrap it on `BottomNavigationBar` that you pass in the `bottomNavigationBar` property

`Gesture Detector` has an `onDoubleTap` method that can be used in your case. 
Here is what you want to do

```
          bottomNavigationBar: GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: (){
              //execute Event
            },
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
                items: [...],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your item widget with `Inkwell`

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: InkWell(
                onDoubleTap: (){
                      print('click');
                    },
                child: youriconwidget();
              ),
              title: Text(""),
            )
```

when you double click

```
I/flutter (11516): click
```

hope it helps

Comment: touch area is greatly reduced by this and not recommended instead consider extending "_BottomNavigationTile" class and in it "InkResponse" already has onDoubleTap you can use